# Knockout: Array Binding Not Working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to bind a simple model to a simple table template:

```
var model = {
    addrText: 'Test address text',
    voters: [
        { name: 'First Voter' },
        { name: 'Second Voter' }
    ],
};

ko.applyBindings( model, document.getElementById('residence') );

<div id="residence">
    <div data-bind="text: addrText" />
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: voters">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But while addrText is output correctly, nothing shows up for the foreach binding. I'm sure I'm missing something amazingly obvious, but I just can't see it.

I'm using knockout v2.2.1, debug version. The model creation and binding are taking place inside a callback triggered by clicking a marker on google maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
<div data-bind="text: addrText" />
```

To:

```
<div data-bind="text: addrText"></div>
```

Knockout doesn't like it when you skip proper closing tags.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQU44/)

Comment: I would never, in a gazillion years, have figured that out on my own. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!